# semantic web reasoner and on the fly rules injection

Tags: semantic-web, pellet, swrl

Is there any semantic web reasoner (e.g. Pellet) that accepts rules (SWRL) on the fly ?
or rules must be hard coded before starting the reasoner

Comment: Please note that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  If you're already using some system, and wondering how to do this, tell us what system and what you've tried.  Otherwise, this is just a library/tool request, and not a great fit for Stack Overflow.    You _might_ have better luck on answers.semanticweb.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you mean by "on the fly".  You can edit a reasoner's rule base, so it is not something you need to set in stone from the outset.  But the reasoner will need to perform some book keeping if you add new rules, or any other axioms, before it can be used to answer queries.  There's no way around that.